# Azure AD SAML 2.0 Tokens are not encrypted

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I have set up Azure AD SAML 2.0 based custom application. But when I am testing that, the token getting exchanged by Azure server to my server is just base 64 encoded.
Also, while debugging in azure ad dashboard, it is showing as "No certificate properties found" but under the "SAML Signing Certificate" section I can clearly see the certificate is present.

SAML Signing Certificate section snip:
[image: SAML-Signing-Certificate]

In below image notice "Token signing certificate" section.
[image: azure-ad-debug-info]

Comment: Signing certificate is not for encryption. Follow the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/howto-saml-token-encryption

Comment: @identigral then how a server could identify if it's a request from the azure server of someone is trying to hack the system? basically the authentication part. how that could be handled? and in the SAML token, it is just base64, that too containing X.509 Certificate. How is it safe?

Comment: The SAML response and/or assertion within the response are signed; encryption is optional and on top of that.

Comment: @identigral can you please share some reference code. I am not able to understand what benefit does "Sign" gives?

Comment: Take a look at [SAML Technical Overview](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf), it explains this well. For reference code on .NET, [Sustainsys](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) has lots of examples.

Comment: @identigral thanks for the doc. it helped a lot. now I have another confusion how can I verify the signature of SAMLResponse? how to authenticate this token? and while configuring azure ad saml 2.0 I didn't get any Private key, any suggestion on what I might have done wrong?